# How to pass html tag parameter from javascript to flask server

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

this is my card where i have passed the title and image

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 200px; background-color: black;" onclick="pass()">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ image[0] }}" alt="k" style="width: 180px;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <a href="{{ url_for('info'}}">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ book[0] }}</h5>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

how to get the value from the a tag and img tag and send it to the particular route ie /info, this is my scripts where i tried to get value

```
<script>
   function pass(){
   var a = document.getElementByTagName('a')
   var img =document.getElementByTagName('img')
   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Js code and check your console

```
<script>
function pass(){ 
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
var img =document.getElementsByTagName('img');
console.log(a[0].outerHTML);
console.log(img[0].outerHTML);
}
</script>
```

Comment: function pass() {
        var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        var w = console.log(a[0].outerHTML);
        window.location = "/info/" + w;

    }

Comment: i have tried and does shows value but it take me to following url http://127.0.0.1:5000/info/undefined

Comment: how to can i pass the value to my flask server do u have any idea